# Using argparse, how can I put the user input into a list?

Tags: python, list, file, argparse, os.path

I need the file path and `os.path.dirname` does not give me the complete path (it does not include the file itself - e.g. `home/a/b` instead of `home/a/b/filename`). Also I need the file name so that I can print it later. Since the argument the user inputs IS the filename, I need a way to store the input into a list.

```
import sys
import argparse
import inspect, os
import os.path

file_list = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()      
    parser.add_argument('file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    for f in args.file:
        with f:
            data = f.read()
            print data
            x = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
            print x
            file_list.append(x+#I need the filename here)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `os.path.abspath(f.name)` to get the absolute filepath that was used to open the file `f`.

However, if you also want the filepath, it may be cleaner to just not convert the type to a fileobject, and do this yourself later, instead of trying to reverse-engineer where the open file came from. This way you will already have the list of filepaths, e.g.:

```
file_list = []

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()      
parser.add_argument('file', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()

for filepath in args.file:
    x = os.path.abspath(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        print data
        file_list.append(x)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. I do need a file name list but I think I can get that from using basename...am I right?

Comment: @varda1316, yep exactly, something like [os.path.basename(filepath) for filepath in args.file] should do it

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full path of a file handler using `os.path.abspath(fl.name)`,
so this should work:

```
import sys
import argparse
import inspect, os
import os.path

file_list = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()      
    parser.add_argument('file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    for f in args.file:
        with f:
            data = f.read()
            print data
            full_path = os.path.abspath(f)
            file_list.append(full_path)
```

For future reference also notice `os.path.basename` which returns only the name component of a path.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
os.path.realpath(f.name)
```

That combines the current curpwd with the file name as recorded in `f.name`.

If that isn't robust enough, you could accept the filename from the user, and open the file yourself.  `FileType` is not essential. It's just a convenience type, most useful in scripts that take input and output files and do something simple with them.  In other words, scripts that immitate common `bash` functions.